# Adding UIButtons to a Cocos2d project

Tags: iphone, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, uibutton

In Cocos2d, I have read that

```
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:someButton];
```

will add a UIView to the main window: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3588

Yet in my code I have this:

```
- (void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish {
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:button];
}
```

But no button is visible. This method is part of a CCLayerColor which is the first scene presented in the app, if that matters. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Edit: I can confirm that the buttons are being added to the windows subviews, because NSLogging

```
[[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] subviews] count]
```

shows a difference when I comment/uncomment the addSubview line. So why isn't the button showing up?

Edit 2:

Thanks to @Marine, I have found that my problem is the way I am declaring my button; using `buttonWithType:` solved the problem, because this code works:

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:button];
```

Can someone explain to me why using this class method works and using `initWithFrame:` doesn't? Because I would rather not create lots of autoreleased objects, and also because I have some UIButton subclasses that do NOT show up when I use the `buttonWithType:` method.

Edit 3 **(Solution)**:

The reason why using anything but `buttonWithType:` doesn't work is that if you do not use that method to create the button, the background color of the button is not set, and by default it is `clearColor`. Using `[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]` or any other color fixes the problem. Also, if using a custom button class like [this one](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/), you might need to manually call `[button awakeFromNib]` if the button isn't connected to a nib.

Comment: I also could not get a button to show up until I used the [UIButton buttonWithType:....] method.  Strange.

Comment: See my edit, I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted the solution to the problem as an edit to the question.

Comment: omg thank you so much!!!!! you have no idea how much this has helped me. i just started doing objective-C/iOS/Cocos2d development, and i didn't even know where to begin tackling this problem. thanks man, you have just made my day!!!!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help you out!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code it would help you

```
-(id) init 
{
    if((self = [super init])) 
    {
    UIView* glView = (UIView*) [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];        
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 250, 250)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionper:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [glView addSubview:btn];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) actionper : (id) sender
{
    printf("\n Stuff of the Code on button Press");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bringsubviewtofront method of the OpenGL window passing the recently added button as the argument. Also make sure that the frame of your button is such that it is in the visible part of the screen. Try playing around with it's position.

Comment: As another test try creating a uiview and adding the button it it then the uiview to the OpenGL window.